# Create an Appointment with EWS in VB.NET, what am i missing?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, exchangewebservices

Hello i want to send a calendar invite to other members, how can i do that in vb.net, 
i added the exchange webreference and can send a normal mail to other people.

here is what i have so far

```
   Public Sub Einladungen()
        Dim esb As New ExchangeServer.ExchangeServiceBinding
        esb.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Session("EX_UserName").ToString, Session("EX_Password").ToString)
        esb.Url = Session("EX_DomainURL")

        Dim appointment As CalendarItemType = New CalendarItemType

        ' Set properties on the appointment.
        appointment.Subject = "Dentist Appointment"
        appointment.Body = New BodyType
        appointment.Body.BodyType1 = BodyTypeType.Text
        appointment.Body.Value = "Agenda Items...."
        appointment.Start = New DateTime(2012, 3, 1, 9, 0, 0)
        appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddHours(2)

        appointment.Location = "Conf Room"
        appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("user1@contoso.com")
        appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("user2@contoso.com")
        appointment.OptionalAttendees.Add("user3@contoso.com")
        ' Save the appointment.
        appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy)
    End Sub
```

Visual Studio tells me that:

> Add is not a member of "System.Array"

and

> "Save" is not a member of "ExchangeServer.CalendarItemType"

and

> The name "SendInvitationMode" is not declared

What am i missing?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Regarding the .Add is not a member. You will need to create a new RequiredAttendee object and add that, not just a string of the email you want to attend as that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have created your own EWS proxy classes by referencing your Exchange web service directly but the sample code you have found is built using the [Exchange Web Service Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/jj220499%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).

So what you should do is to [download the EWS Managed API](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30141), add a reference to Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll, and change the beginning of your code into something similar to this:

```
Dim esb As New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
esb.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Session("EX_UserName").ToString, Session("EX_Password").ToString)
esb.Url = Session("EX_DomainURL")

Dim appointment As new Appointment(esb);
// ... the rest of your code here.
```

You might want to have a look at this example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633661(v=exchg.80).aspx